# apt-get upgrade fails with "adduser: The user `messagebus' already exists. Exiting."

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, dbus

Got this today when trying to upgrade the software on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
Setting up dbus (1.4.18-1ubuntu1.5) ...
adduser: The user `messagebus' already exists. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
 dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus-x11 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 dbus
 dbus-x11
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm tempted to delete the user messagebus and retry. Would that be a good way to fix this? Or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `dpkg --configure -a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the user id the messagebus user has.

First check what this command outputs:

```
grep messagebus /etc/passwd /etc/group
```

It should show something like this:

```
/etc/passwd:messagebus:x:102:104::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
/etc/group:messagebus:x:104:
```

Then take a look at `/etc/adduser.conf` and search for "`FIRST_SYSTEM_UID=111`".
As you can see the ID of messagebus is 102 / 104 and below the value of `FIRST_SYSTEM_UID`.
Simply change FIRST_SYSTEM_UID to 100 and save (as root/sudo).

Then the upgrade should run without any errors.

---

*Reference: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=634475*

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot! Curious, any idea why `FIRST_SYSTEM_UID` was `111` rather than `100`? https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.2.2 suggests it should indeed be `100`.

Comment: I dont know. It is 111 on several of my machines (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the missing group:

```
addgroup messagebus
```